# php random paring of up to 8 elements

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I already have a basic script done, but i need to add some rules as well - if the user pair already exsits then skip. it has to be random paring of up to 8 elements. I am not sure i am on the right track here, any suggestions would be much appreciated. Here's the script i have till now:

```
$array = array('up1','up2','up3','up4','up5','up6', 'up7', 'up8', 'up9', 'up10', 'up11',            'up12', 'up13', 'up14');
$result = array();

$first = $element1 = array_shift($array); // get first element and save it

while(count($array)) {

$element2 = array_rand($array);

// associate elements
$result[$element1] = $array[$element2];

// random element becomes next element
$element1 = $array[$element2];

// delete the random element
array_splice($array, $element2, 1);
}

// associate last element with the first one
$result[$element1] = $first;

print_r($result);
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your current script/where does it fail? Instead of being real clever, try to solve this as simple as possible first

Comment: Is your question solved?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm understanding it correctly, but you want to make two random pairs of an array?

```
$array = array('up1', 'up2', 'up3', 'up4', 'up5', 'up6', 'up7', 'up8', 'up9', 'up10', 'up11', 'up12', 'up13', 'up14');
shuffle($array);
print_r(array_chunk($array, 2));
```

Prints out randomly;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => up5
            [1] => up13
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => up7
            [1] => up9
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => up6
            [1] => up4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => up11
            [1] => up14
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => up12
            [1] => up3
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => up8
            [1] => up10
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => up2
            [1] => up1
        )

)
```